# Subgroup structure of $\mathrm{SL}(2, p^2)$ and its irreducible characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, finite-fields

I am taking a course in representation theory of finite groups, and somehow I ended up getting assigned to write a report on subgroup structure and irreducible characters of $\mathrm{SL}(2,7)$ and $\mathrm{SL}(2,9)$ with a view towards generalizing them for arbitrary primes. I followed Liebeck's book *Representations and Characters of Groups* and though I find it an extremely beautiful and inspiring book I would be glad if I had more resources on these. (Specifically, what is the general strategy of finding subgroup structure aside from determining the trivial ones; also how does the fact that 7 is a prime and 9 a prime power change the scenario?

Also, how does representing these groups over $\mathbb{C}$ help us to visualize the groups better than what they are? And what is so special about these groups? And like the special linear groups over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is there any geometric interpretation of these groups?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I can see subgroups of order $p,\ p{-}1$ and $p{+}1$ inside $\mathrm{SL}(2,p)$:

The existence of a subgroup of order $p$ is guaranteed by Sylow's theorem, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 
a & 0 \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$ where $a$ is a nonzero element of the field gives us a subgroup with cardinality $p{-}1$, and subgroups of order $p{+}1$ can be constructed from action of $\mathrm{GL}(2,p)$ on a two dimensional vector space over the finite field.

Are there any more obvious possible subgroups? And is there anything special about $\mathrm{SL}(2,7)$?

Comment: This sounds like a very difficult project without any hints on how to start.  I personally know nothing in this area, but I know the conventional reference may be of your interest: Carter's book, Finite Groups of Lie type.  Have you looked it up yet?

Comment: thanks, I saw through the book, and to be honest it is a bit to advanced for my current mathematical understandings, But as you pointed out this project is not exactly easy and I believe I am not the right person talking about these :)

Comment: PSL(2,p) is actually a homomomorphic image of SL(2,p), it is not usually a subgroup. Also, I think you mean $a^{-1}$ to be the second diagonal entry in your diagonal matrix above- probably just a typo. Hint for another subgroup: Think about invertible upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Oh yes I am sorry for stating PSL(2,p) is a subgroup, and thanks for the new subgroup that you mentioned...and i will fix the typo

Comment: IIRC a general line of attack here is to first identify irreducible representations of first the subgroup of diagonal matrices, then then of the upper triangular matrices, and then induce those to reps of all of $SL_2$.

Comment: This is done/outlined in for example [Kowalski's course notes](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/representation-theory.html).

Comment: A semi-obvious subgroup is the quaternion group. Less obvious is $SL_2(3)$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054917/is-sl2-3-a-subgroup-of-sl2-p-for-p3.